# How can I move a list of files from a dictionary to a directory?

Tags: python, join, path, operating-system, rename

first time asking a question here so feel free to let me know if I'm not doing anything correctly.

I'm essentially trying to append the txt files from the dictionaries (values) to a specific directory with os and path. I've tried this but I get a type error. `TypeError: join() argument must be str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not 'list'`

Here is my code below. I look forward to your responses :)

```
import os

ROOT = os.getcwd()
DATA_ROOT = os.path.join(ROOT, "src/data/initial")

def classify(arg: dict):
    for key, value in arg.items():
        folder = os.path.join(DATA_ROOT, key)
        file = os.path.join(folder, value)
        
        os.rename(DATA_ROOT, file)
    return

# Dictionary with files that I am trying to move/create in the path
# .....src/data/initial/personal and .....src/data/initial/work
categories = {
    "personal": ["todos.txt", "bookmarks.txt"],
    "work": ["customers.csv", "jobs.csv"]
}

print(classify(categories))
```

Comment: file = os.path.join(folder, value) # value is a value of categories, so it is a list - that is not what is expected by os.path.join

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over `value` (as these are lists) and then proceed as you wish:

```
def classify(arg: dict):
    for key, value in arg.items():
        for f in value:
            file = os.path.join(DATA_ROOT, key, f)
            # Do stuff
    return
```

**PS:** You might want to consider the `shutil` builtin library for files/folders operations (e.g. `shutil.move`).

Comment: Thank you I will take a look at it. It was part of an exercise for learning os and path. For some reason it's still not working. I tried os.replace(..., ...) too. Will update once I find a solution that is working

Comment: `folder = os.path.join(DATA_ROOT, key)` should be in the outer loop, not the inner loop.

Comment: @wwii True. Opted for something even simpler.